# A free test management tool (Not web-based but a downloadable tool on windows 7)

Tags: testing, version-control

Is there any free downloadable test management tool for  Windows 7.

I do not want to use any web-based tool where-in I have to sign-up.

Comment: What do you need in a Test Management tool? 

Notepad, Excel and Word work great for recording tests.

Comment: I need a tool that can map things better. Like the requirements, testcases etc. Presently I maintain testcase in excel, requirements are in word document, bug report is in another excel sheet. Maintaining all this and the requirement, testcase, bug id gets difficult. I am looking for a tool wherein i can do all this at one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the test management tools and bug trackers I've used (SpiraTest, Quality Center, Jira) have been web-based. My personal opinion on test management tools, for a lone / single tester, is that they are often too complex and too restrictive to be useful. Sure you can link requirements to tests but you have to input everything into a requirements section, then link it to each test set. Seems much easier to just create a matrix or two in Excel and track your coverage.

All test management tools also seem to think its possible to record your tests in a simple step by step manner with expected and actual results. I personally find this type of system to be too restrictive. A good test design may not yield itself to simple step by step instructions.

Having a good bug tracker that you and your development team can use is an excellent idea. There are lots of free / cheap options however they are all also web-based. [Bugzilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) is free and takes a bit of time to setup, however you can probably find a free VM somewhere which will get you up and running quickly (Google around). [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) is a free wiki of sort with some bug reporting abilities. [SpiraTest](http://inflectra.com/spiratest/default.aspx) is cheap - like $50 for a single user and has test managment and bug tracking capabilities, although if you have a few developers you'll want a larger license that may cost upwards of $200/300.

I personally like [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/overview) and Atlassian's software. I'm playing around with Jira, Confluence and Bonfire for my testing. I can create wikis, etc. for my test ideas in Confluence, report bugs in Jira and use Bonfire for exploratory testing. If you want to host the software yourself (install it on VMs on your machine) Atlassian has this really cool deal called [Starter](http://www.atlassian.com/software/starter/overview) for just $10/each item.

My experience has taught me that having a web-based bug tracking tool is a must have but Test Management tools tend to be a waste. However I encourage you to look around and explore. Most, if not all, of these tools have trial programs. You'll have to sign up / register but that's the cost of doing business. Wikipedia has [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_management_tools) on Test management Tools so have at it.

Comment: Needless to say I haven't come across a Windows 7, non-web based, downloadable Test Management tool. Then again it doesn't really make sense for anyone to create one either.